# Is there a more concise way to write an "is_owned_by?" method on a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

This is fairly trivial but I'm wondering if there is a simpler or more concise way to write this:

```
def is_owned_by?(user_id)
   return false unless self.user_id.eql?(user_id)
   true
end
```

Comment: I think it would make more sense to deal with user instances, rather than IDs.

Comment: The answer below seems obvious now, but your comment is interesting because I could do: self.user.id.eql?(user_id) but I'm not sure if there's any advantage to that as it might be slightly more expensive because it has to look up the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something just running the comparison will result in ruby returning the proper boolean:

```
def is_owned_by?(user_id)
  self.user_id.eql?(user_id)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You comparasion already returns a boolean and there is no need for `self` on getters:

```
def is_owned_by?(owner_id)
  user_id == owner_id
end
```

Comment: without self it always returns true.. not sure why.

Comment: It return always `true` if you give the argument the same name that your attribute. Therefore I named it `other_id`.